# How find google play deployment private key

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-keystore

I uploaded my android apk to google play and enable google app siginig, so google play will sign my apk with its deployment sign key!

Also i want to sign my apk for publishing in another android market. for users who uses both markets, my apk from both markets should have same sign key.

So my question is here, that how can i sign my apk with google play deployment sign?? i can just download deployment certificate from google play console, how can i find the private key??

Comment: given what you write, I'd doubt there's such possibility, because google probably has checked the uploaded app and decided it's safe to sign it, so they won't give you the opportunity to upload other (potentially harmful) app somewhere else with the same key. But still that's just a guess.

Comment: @Antek, the problem in here, i can't upload my app with google sign in another market. and for example when user download my app from google play, cant update next version from another market because of different sign!!!

Comment: Can you suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If Google Play signs the app for you, you don't have access to the key.

Normally in this case you would just sign it with a different key in each market. Most uses of the signing key won't mind (eg most cloud APIs let you register more than one key). And you usually don't want one App store updating an app installed by a different app store.

Comment: It's not a good solution! when end user download my app from google play, cant update next version from another market because of different sign!!!

Comment: Google Play won't update apps from other markets anyway. Most markets are the same. Which particular markets do you think the user will install from and which markets do you think users will update from?

Comment: the https://cafebazaar.ir/ market. Now i update all my apps from both google play and cafebazaar and it's ok!